# Working example of countdown timer with smooth progress bar

Tags: android, android-progressbar, countdowntimer

I've seen many similar questions but I can't find any code that actually works so please modify this example so the progress bar moves smoothly.

[activity_main.xml](https://pastebin.com/nztrU9LX)

I've seen some answers that increase the max and reduce the time interval but I don't see it working properly. There are other answers that use the animator class and work fine but then I don't know how to update the numbers.

```
package com.example.arturo_2.countdowntimertutorial;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private long timeCountInMilliSeconds = 1 * 60 * 1000;

    private ProgressBar progressBarCircle;
    private EditText editTextMinute;
    private TextView textViewTime;
    private Button buttonDecrease;
    private Button buttonIncrease;
    private Button buttonStop;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // method call to initialize the views
        initViews();
        // method call to initialize the listeners
        initListeners();

        start();
    }

    /**
     * method to initialize the views
     */
    private void initViews() {
        progressBarCircle = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarCircle);
        editTextMinute = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMinute);
        textViewTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
        buttonDecrease = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDecrease);
        buttonIncrease = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonIncrease);
        buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fab_stop);
    }

    /**
     * method to initialize the click listeners
     */
    private void initListeners() {
        buttonDecrease.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonIncrease.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * method to increase timer value
     */
    private void increase() {
        timeCountInMilliSeconds += 15 * 1000;
        setProgressBarValues();
    }

    /**
     * method to decrease timer value
     */
    private void decrease() {
        timeCountInMilliSeconds -= 15 * 1000;
        setProgressBarValues();
    }

    /**
     * method to cancel count down timer
     */
    private void stop() {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }

    /**
     * implemented method to listen clicks
     *
     * @param view
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonDecrease:
                decrease();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonIncrease:
                increase();
                break;
            case R.id.fab_stop:
                stop();
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * method to initialize the values for count down timer
     */
    private void setTimerValues() {
        int time = 0;
        if (!editTextMinute.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            // fetching value from edit text and type cast to integer
            time = Integer.parseInt(editTextMinute.getText().toString().trim());
        }
        // assigning values after converting to milliseconds
        timeCountInMilliSeconds = time * 60 * 1000;
        setProgressBarValues();
    }

    /**
     * method to set circular progress bar values
     */
    private void setProgressBarValues() {
        progressBarCircle.setMax((int) timeCountInMilliSeconds / 1000);
        progressBarCircle.setProgress((int) timeCountInMilliSeconds / 1000);
    }

    /**
     * method to start count down timer
     */
    private void start() {
        setTimerValues();
        startCountDownTimer();
    }

    /**
     * method to start count down timer
     */
    private void startCountDownTimer() {
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeCountInMilliSeconds, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                textViewTime.setText(hmsTimeFormatter(millisUntilFinished));
                progressBarCircle.setProgress((int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                textViewTime.setText(hmsTimeFormatter(timeCountInMilliSeconds));
                setProgressBarValues(); // call to initialize the progress bar values
            }
        }.start();
        countDownTimer.start();
    }

    /**
     * method to convert millisecond to time format
     *
     * @param milliSeconds
     * @return mm:ss time formatted string
     */
    private String hmsTimeFormatter(long milliSeconds) {

        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliSeconds),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(milliSeconds) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliSeconds)));

        return hms;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give let us know what's not working about the code you posted.

Comment: It's working, it just doesn't work as I want. I want the progress bar to update smoothly.

Answer (score 3):

[MainActivity.java](https://pastebin.com/Fyhd8sEK), [activity_main.xml](https://pastebin.com/UxgbAFrA)

```
private void setProgressBarValues() {
        progressBarCircle.setMax((int) timeCountInMilliSeconds / 50);
        progressBarCircle.setProgress((int) timeCountInMilliSeconds / 1000);
    }

private void startCountDownTimer() {
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeCountInMilliSeconds, 50) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                textViewTime.setText(hmsTimeFormatter(millisUntilFinished));
                progressBarCircle.setProgress((int) (millisUntilFinished / 50));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                textViewTime.setText(hmsTimeFormatter(timeCountInMilliSeconds));
                setProgressBarValues(); // call to initialize the progress bar values
            }
        }.start();
        countDownTimer.start();
    }
```